# Suggest the way to detect file changes in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using `run on save` visual studio code extension but it runs command on every save command.what i need is to run command only if any file changed

Comment: Is this all info you can give to us?

Comment: That is just what is happening. You change/save a file ==> something runs

Comment: yes, it can be useful for on save auto deployment.But vscode has run on save extension which runs on ctrl+s press that i don't want.it should detect file changes first if any, then do something.